# Is it possible to attach a remote X11 session as second monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, x11-forwarding, xpra

I am trying to use the monitor of a remote system as second monitor on my local system. I can use X11 ssh forwarding but this is not doing what I want, because then I have to set the DISPLAY variable to :10. And a program now only sees the monitor(s) on the remote system. So basically what I want is to multiplex two X11 displays (for example :0 and :10) to a single displays containing two monitors. I have already tried to use xpra. The --sharing=yes options gives me the possibility to connect more than one client per time, but they share one monitor.

So the goal: have a display (e.g :1) that when set, applications sees two monitors as it would be when they both connected to the same computer

I already thought about to use VNC, but I'd prefer a solution with lower network traffic, since the target network is not the best.

Comment: VNC is lower traffic than X11

Comment: Thanks for that hint. But I think I have a solution using xpra which is (at least for what I read) more efficient than VNC.